# Td inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new at jQuery/Javascript.
I'm trying to know if to `td` element has more than one `li` element with text..
I have the follow `td` if has more than one `li` element with text. 
Code sample:

```
<td class="tdClass"/>
  <div id="div1Id" class="div1Class">
    <ul class="ulClass">
        <li id="" class="rtLI rtFirst">
            <div class="rtMid">
                <div>Text1</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="" class="rtLI rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">
                <div>Text2</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

 </div>
</td>
```

And the follow if i have only one `li` element without text:

```
<td class="tdClass"/>
<div id="div1Id" class="div1Class">
    <ul class="ulClas">
        <li id="" class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">&nbsp;</div>
        </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</td>
```

How i can know at the simple way (jQuery/javascript) if to my td has "inner elements"?
I see thats if has element the first `li` item have only `rtLI rtFirst` class and if not `rtLI rtFirst reLast` but how can i know that from my code?
Thanks

Comment: Both have inner elements what is the difference ?

Comment: The diffrent that the first exapmle i have two "li" elements with text and the second exapmle i have only one "li" element without text

Comment: Nothing in your question has anything to do with either javascript or jQuery!

Comment: I'm fix my question

Comment: @Jamiec, i want to know if i have li element with text by using javascript/jquery

Comment: The only difference between your first HTML snippet and the second, is that the second has 1 list items inside the unordered list, the first has two

Comment: @Jamiec, right..thats what i'm trying to know by using javascript/jquery

Comment: To be clear; You want to know how to add a new `li` using jQuery?

Comment: @Jamiec, No, i want to know if i have only one 'li' with inner div element with empty text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm basing this answer on your comment

> i want to know if i have only one 'li' with inner div element with empty text.

As the wording of your actual question is less clear.

---

There appears to be a number of ways to achieve what you're after, they all begin with having a reference to your `div` element. In jQuery, you select an element by Id using a `#` selector

```
var $div = $('#divId');
```

(Note, as a common convention you can prefix variables which relate to a jQuery object with `$` to distinguish them from other variables. Not essential, but a useful convention)

From there, your element with only blank text seems to have both classes `rtFirst` and `rtLast`. So you can count the number of children with both of these classes. If that count is equal to 1, then you have that element.

```
if($divId.find('.rtFirst.rtLast').length === 1){
    // you only have the one element with both rtFirst _and_ rtLast
}
```

Another way would be to count the number of children of the `ul` within your div

```
var numberofLis = $divId.children('ul').children().length;
if(numberofLis === 1){
    // you only have the one element
}
```

And there are countless other ways to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

** Please note that you can not have this `<td class="tdClass"/>`, it should be `<td class="tdClass">` instead, without **`/`** in it because this means it's a "[self-closing](https://www.quora.com/Which-HTML-tags-are-self-closing)" tag and `td` tag could not be a self-closing tag, you have `</td>` to close it.

```js
// loop through the tds with tdClass class
$('#theTable .tdClass').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      matched = $this.find('.rtMid');
  
  // if we find only one .rtMid in the td..
  if (matched.length === 1) {
    
    // and its trimmed text is empty, then we have a match
    if (matched.text().trim() === '') {
      //match found, your code here
      $this.css({'outline': '2px solid red'});
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="theTable">
  <tr>
    <!-- two divs with text in them, No Match -->
    <td class="tdClass">
      <div id="div1Id" class="div1Class">
        <ul class="ulClass">
          <li id="" class="rtLI rtFirst">
            <div class="rtMid">
              <div>Text1</div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="" class="rtLI rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">
              <div>Text2</div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    <!-- one div with no text in it, MATCH -->
    <td class="tdClass">
      <div id="div1Id" class="div1Class">
        <ul class="ulClas">
          <li id="" class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">&nbsp;</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    <!-- two divs without text in them, No Match -->
    <td class="tdClass">
      <div id="div1Id" class="div1Class">
        <ul class="ulClas">
          <li id="" class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid"></div>
          </li>
          <li id="" class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
    <!-- one div with text in it, No Match -->
    <td class="tdClass">
      <div id="div1Id" class="div1Class">
        <ul class="ulClas">
          <li id="" class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">abc</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How useful is a code dump, with no description or explnation to an obviously quite inexperienced programmer?

Answer (score 1):

Full example code with finding only those tds with more then one li:

```js
//function search for all tds with more then one li element inside
function getAllTdsWithLiMoreThenOne(rootSelector){
 
   return $(rootSelector).find("td").has("li").filter(function(){
        
        return $(this).find("li").length>1;
   });
}

//after document is loaded
$(function(){

  //here in getAllTdsWithLiMoreThenOne("table") you get list of tds
  console.log("Tds with more than one li : "+getAllTdsWithLiMoreThenOne("table").length);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="td1" class="tdClass"/>
  <div id="div1Id" class="div1Class">
    <ul class="ulClass">
        <li id="" class="rtLI rtFirst">
            <div class="rtMid">
                <div>Text1</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="" class="rtLI rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">
                <div>Text2</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

 </div>

</td>
<td id="td2">
    
    <div id="div2Id" class="div1Class">
    <ul class="ulClass">
        <li id="" class="rtLI rtFirst">
            <div class="rtMid">
                <div>Text1</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

 </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Function **getAllTdsWithLiMoreThenOne(selector)** returns collection of Jquery objects, so You have on plate all tds with more then one li inside.

PS. inserting divs in tables is not good practice.